# Simple bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

im new to bash scripting and tring to make a script

goal: reciving 2 names (1 - logfilename 2- program name) the program should compile the program

and send both outputs to a log

if success then write "compile V" and return 0 else compile X and return number

i tried

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc {$2}.c -Wall -g -o $2> $1 2>&1
exit
```

and i have no idea how to check if it did or didnt success and the to echo V or X

edit:
thx for you guys, i got this

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc {$2}.c -Wall -g -o ${2}>${1} 2>&1

if (($?==0));then
    echo Compile V
[else
    echo compile X]
fi
exit
```

but all the if parts are still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check exit status `gcc` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# execute gcc command
gcc "$2".c -Wall -g -o "$2"> "$1" 2>&1

# grab exit status of gcc
ret=$?

# write appropriate message as per return status value
((ret == 0)) && echo "compile V" || echo "compile X"

# return the exit status of gcc
exit $ret
```

Comment: thx very much this look soo cool, can you please explain this line

"((ret == 0)) && echo "compile V" || echo "compile X""

Comment: `((ret==0))` executed `if $ret is 0` condition and `&&` part is executed when condition is true and `||` part executed when condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the success of a program in bash by command `$?` if `echo $?` = 0 then success else fail.

Comment: so i have to send it to another script?
i mean i know $? only as input to script

Answer (score 0):

this code should work :

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -v ${2}.c -Wall -g -o ${2}>${1} 2>&1
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc "$2"".c" -Wall -g -o "$2" 2>&1 >"$1"
#check for error of previous command
if $? ; then echo compile V >>"$1"
else echo compile X >>"$1"; fi
exit
```

Comment: At that point, why not just run `if gcc ...; then success-case; else fail-case; fi` and not need to use `$?` at all?

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -- "$0"
```

#1
this is also my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: No arguments provided. Please provide at least one number."
    exit 1
fi

sum=0

for arg in "$@"; do
    sum=$((sum + arg))
done

echo $sum
```

#2
this is also a possible solution

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <input_file>"
    exit 1
fi

input_file="$1"

wget {link_here}
while IFS= read -r word; do
    if grep -q "\<$word\>" usr/share/dict/british-english; then
        echo "$word in dictionary"
    else
        echo "$word not in dictionary"
    fi
done < "$input_file"

rm wbritish_*.deb
rm -rf usr
```

#3
this is also a possible solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter threshold (default is 12): " threshold_input

if [[ ! "$threshold_input" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Using default threshold value: 12"
    threshold=12
else
    threshold="$threshold_input"
fi

echo "Threshold = $threshold"

df -h | awk -v threshold="$threshold" '$1 ~ /^\/dev/ && $5+0 > threshold {print "WARNING: Partition \"" $1 "\" used " $5}'
```